# List<> Contains Issue

Tags: c#

**Edit - Check is Moved to The Else, Looping & Multiple Object Changes are Now Prime Issue**

I need 5 Teams objects To Play Against each other (Each must play against the Other 4 teams)

The Check had to be in the ELSE statement, Now the Only Problem left is the Scores
add and subtract from ALL the teams same time, and i only play once, i need them to loop
so that they all played against everyone

I Started off like this. Yet i don't know how to go about doing this

```
//This is the list i check against and add players to when the team
//Played against them

List<string> played = new List<string>();

//Teamlist Holds Objects of type Team 
//Contructor - (TeamName,Points,Wins,Losses,Draws,totalpoints)
//string, rest are int type

foreach (var item in Teamlist)
{
    if (played.Contains(item.Teamname))
    {
    //Played against them already or is the same name as their own
    }
    else
    {
     //Add own Name on Check
    played.Add(item.Teamname);

        //Looping here against all Teams Entered to be played against
        //How do i go about doing this?

        //If Team 1 Wins Team 2 - This is just 2 Randoms between 1
        //and 10
        if (rand1 > rand2)
        {
            item.WinGame(); //Increments Team win Points
        }
        else if (rand1 == rand2)
        {
            item.DrawGame(); //Draw awards no points
        }
        else
        {
            item.LoseGame(); //Lose Points
        }
    }
}

foreach (var item in Teamlist)
{
    //This ToString() looks like this
    //return string.Format("Team Name : {0} \t {1} \t {2} \t {3} \t 
    //{4} \t {5}", teamname, points, win, loss, draw, totalpoints);
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Well you are adding an item to the list, then immediately checking if that item is in the list.  I don't see how it would ever hit the else.

Comment: It never reaches else because always add the item you then check for.  Do you mean something other than Teamname, like MyTeamname or whatever?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because you made a little error:

First you add `item.Teamname`

```
//Add own Name on Check
played.Add(item.Teamname);
```

Then you check if the previously added `item.Teammname` is within the list -- always true:

```
if (played.Contains(item.Teamname))
{
```

Comment: Oh yes i see that... Sorry for not indicating that i know this. Its the "Workaround" of getting to check for itself and other "Played" teams that i seem to not be able to produce the logic for

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: This is wrong. It would give you both home and away games.**

What about taking the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the list of teams to give you the list of matches to be played. With Linq it's pretty easy:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var teams = new[]
    {
        new { Name = "Team 1"},
        new { Name = "Team 2"},
        new { Name = "Team 3"},
        new { Name = "Team 4"},
        new { Name = "Team 5"}
    };

    var matches = 
        // here we loop over all the items in the teams collection. 
        // "teamA" is our loop variable.
        from teamA in teams

        // here we loop over all the items in the teams collection again.
        // like a nested foreach (in) 
        // "teamB" is our loop variable.
        from teamB in teams

        // this is like an if(teamA.Name != teamB.Name) within our nested foreach loops
        where teamA.Name != teamB.Name

        // the select says how we want to create our collection of results.
        // Here we're creating a new anonymous object containing the two rival teams.
        select new { Team1 = teamA, Team2 = teamB };

    foreach (var match in matches)
    {
        var result = PlayMatch(match.Team1, match.Team2);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} played {1} The result was {2}", 
            match.Team1.Name, 
            match.Team2.Name, 
            result);
    }
}

private static string PlayMatch(object team1, object team2)
{
    // Left as an exercise for the OP.
    return "...";
}
```

Comment: This is waaaay wrong. It would give you both home and away games.

Comment: Unfortunately im very unfamiliar with linq

Comment: @DesmondSmith The two `from ...` statements are essentially two `foreach` statements. We're doing a nested loop over the teams, checking if their name matches and `select`ing  them into a new collection. I'll annotate the code above.

Answer (score 1):

here lies your problem:

```
played.Add(item.Teamname);

if (played.Contains(item.Teamname))
```

The first line adds the team name to the played list, the second line checks if the team name is in the list. This should always be true, so you never get into the else path...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `teamList is IList<Team>`:

```
for(int i = 0;     i < teamList.Count() - 1; i++)
for(int j = i + 1; j < teamList.Count();     j++)
{
   var team1 = teamList[i];
   var team2 = teamList[j];
   // will execute for each pair once
}
```

For 5 teams:

- 0 plays 1,2,3,4
- 1 plays 2,3,4
- 2 plays 3,4
- 3 plays 4

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code, you need to move `played.Add(item.Teamname);` inside your else branch, so you're only adding the team name to the `played` collection if they haven't played them.

```
foreach (var item in Teamlist)
{
    //Add own Name on Check
    // played.Add(item.Teamname); // <---- Move from here

    if (played.Contains(item.Teamname))
    {
    //Played against them already or is the same name as their own
    }
    else
    {
        //Add own Name on Check
        played.Add(item.Teamname); // <---- To here

        ...
```

Comment: That sounds like a problem somewhere in your Win/Lose/Draw methods and isn't part of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Method originally played each team twice. Your notion of a played list is actually required. See below.

Edit: Here's another method, which may prove faster.

```
void PlayRound(Team[] teams)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < teams.Length; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < teams.Length; j++)
            PlayMatch(teams[i], teams[j]);
}

/// <summary>
/// Plays a full round, one match per team.
/// </summary>
void PlayRound(List<Team> teams)
{
    List<Team> played = new List<Team>(); // keep track of teams in the outer loop

    foreach (Team teamA in teams)
    {
        foreach (Team teamB in teams)
        {
            if (teamA == teamB || played.Contains(teamB))
                continue;
            else
                PlayMatch(teamA, teamB);
        }
        played.Add(teamA); // add outer loop team to ensure one match per pairing
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Plays a match.
/// </summary>
void PlayMatch(Team teamA, Team teamB)
{
    int scoreA = rand.Next();
    int scoreB = rand.Next();

    if (scoreA > scoreB)
    {
        teamA.Win();
        teamB.Lose();
    }
    else if (scoreA == scoreB)
    {
        teamA.Draw();
        teamB.Draw();
    }
    else
    {
        teamB.Win();
        teamA.Lose();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very similar to what i would like to try. i think i will try this approach first

Comment: This will give you both home and away games.

Comment: Greg, you're absolutely right. This will wind up with two matches per team.

Comment: I've made some minor changes. @DesmondSmith, your original notion of a played list was on the right track. As others have noted, it was the order that you operated on it that was at fault. See revised method above.

Comment: Very helpfull approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in Teamlist)
{
    //Add own Name on Check
    played.Add(item.Teamname);

    if (played.Contains(item.Teamname))
    {
        //Played against them already or is the same name as their own
    }
```

This is always true? You add the name and next you'll try to find it (you just added it....)

```
played.Add(item.Teamname);
```

Should be at the end of the foreach scope i guess

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one loop in your logic.

Based on the code you provided, here is what happens :

1. Add current Teamname to played list
2. Check if current Teamname is in played list

You should add another loop between steps 1 and 2 to loop on all teams and execute the game logic.